# Repository and Inheritance

Tags: c#, inheritance, repository, datamapper

Currently I have a inheritance structure, let's say Employee and Manager class, inherit from Person abstract class
Should I implement one repository for each concrete class or one repository for the whole inheritance structure? Personally I feel one repository for each concrete class is more correct
Below is my implementation for this approach. I use Data Mapper pattern together with Repository but have some difficulties while implementing this approach: some of the methods I don't know where to put except Data Mapper class, but very awkward to put there also

```
public enum PersonType
{
    Unknown = 0,
    Employee = 1,
    Manager = 2
}

public abstract class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }    
    public PersonType Type { get; set; }

    //Omitted properties and methods
}

public class Employee : Person
{
    public string EmployeeNo { get; set; }

    //Omitted properties and methods
}

public class Manager : Person
{
    public string ManagerNo { get; set; }

    //Omitted properties and methods
}
```

Below are the mappers class:

```
public interface IMapper
{
    bool CanMap(PersonType type);
    Person MapFrom(DataRow dataRow);

    //This method is awkward to put here
    SqlCommand CreateUpdateCommandFrom(Person person);  
}

public abstract class MapperBase : IMapper
{
    public abstract bool CanMap(PersonType type);
    public abstract Person MapFrom(DataRow dataRow);
    public abstract SqlCommand CreateUpdateCommandFrom(Person person);

    protected T MapCommonPropertiesFrom<T>(DataRow dataRow) where T : Person, new()
    {
        return new T
        {
            //Populate common properties like id, name, age
        };
    }
}

public class EmployeeMapper : MapperBase
{
    public override bool CanMap(PersonType type)
    {
        return type == PersonType.Employee;
    }

    public override Person MapFrom(DataRow dataRow)
    {
        Employee employee = MapCommonPropertiesFrom<Employee>(dataRow);
        //Populate employee properties
        return employee;
    }

    public override SqlCommand CreateUpdateCommandFrom(Person person)
    {
        SqlCommand updateCmd = new SqlCommand();
        //Set parameters for updateCmd from person properties
        return updateCmd;
    }
}

//Similar class for ManagerMapper
```

Below is a register class to lookup for mapper class

```
public static class MapperRegistry
{
    private static List<IMapper> _Mappers = RegisterMappers();

    private static List<IMapper> RegisterMappers()
    {
        return new List<IMapper>
        {
            new EmployeeMapper()
            //ManagerMapper
        };
    }

    public static IMapper FindMapperFor(PersonType type)
    {
        foreach (IMapper eachMapper in _Mappers)
        {
            if (eachMapper.CanMap(type))
            {
                return eachMapper;
            }
        }

        throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("Cannot find mapper for {0}", type));
    }
}
```

And last class is repository class

```
public class PersonRepository
{   
    public Person FindBy(int id)
    {
        //Execute query command in db, get datatable back, store each person
        DataTable returnedData = ExecuteQueryCommand(id);
        PersonType type = int.Parse(returnedData.Rows[0], "Id");
        IMapper mapper = MapperRegistry.FindMapperFor(type);
        return mapper.MapFrom(returnedData.Rows[0]);
    }

    private DataTable ExecuteQueryCommand(int id)
    {
        //Execute query command in db
        return new DataTable();
    }

    public void Update<T>(T person) where T : Person
    {
        IMapper mapper = MapperRegistry.FindMapperFor(person.Type);
        SqlCommand updateCmd = mapper.CreateUpdateCommandFrom(person);
        //Execute update command
    }
}
```

The one I feel not right is the CreateUpdateCommandFrom(), currently put in Mapper class, by right should be put in respository class, but in general repository class, we don't know specific properties of child class like EmployeeNo in Employee class and ManagerNo in Manager class, so we cannot create common SqlCommand in repository

Is there any better approach?
Thank you very much

Comment: Seems like you are really re-inventing the wheel with the mapper classes and rolling your own ORM.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any better approach? Thank you very much

Yes there is a better approach.

As you are using a SQL database avoid reinventing the wheel and use an [ORM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) tool such as [nHibernate](http://nhforge.org) or [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ef.aspx) instead, preferably with LINQ support.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestion, but due to limitation in my company, we cannot use entity framework or nhibernate, that's why I need to build one manually